# How can i iterate through all System.Data.SqlDbType s?

Tags: c#, loops, sqldbtype

As my questeion above i would like to iterate through ALL `System.Data.SqlDbType`s. How is this possible?

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
foreach (var type in System.Data.SqlDbType(s))
{
   ..code         
}
```

I know System.Data.SqlDbType is no List or IEnumerable :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this:

```
foreach (SqlDbType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SqlDbType)))
{
   ..code
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to store them instantly into a List? For example `public readonly List<SqlDbType> Types = new List<SqlDbType>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SqlDbType)));`

Comment: sure, but you need to cast it first, like this: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(SqlDbType)).Cast<SqlDbType>().ToList()`

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry i didn't know `.Cast<Type>()` :D